# Text error format of cvs file after export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export-to-csv

I got an issue when export csv file.
I try use \uFEFF, but it not working :(((

```
const BOM = "\uFEFF";
const sample = "sep=,\n" + data1;
const csv = new Blob([BOM + sample], {
  type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"
});
```

[image]

Comment: What operating system is this?  Windows is not smart about UTF-8.

Comment: I am using mac with chrome browser

Comment: What?  How is Chrome involved?